# Assigning a filename to a variable while traversing through multiple folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch programming. I need to traverse through all files in a directory, get the filename, assign it to a variable and then call a subroutine to perform a task. I am stuck in the first task of assigning filename to a variable.
My code displays the file names correctly here

```
@echo off

for /R  %%f in (*.*) do (
echo %%~nf
)
```

when I assign the name to a variable, only one value gets printed.

```
@echo off

for /R  %%f in (*.*) do (
set xFilename=%%~nf
echo %%xFilename
)
```

I am missing some basic concept here. Please help.

Comment: See discussion about *Delayed environment variable expansion* is `set /?`. However you are doing an unnecessary step. Pass `%%F` to the function. See `call /?`.

Comment: either just `echo %%~nf` or with [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082): `echo !xFilename!`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the response.